# Dynamic hls_path based on stream name in rtmp module with nginx

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I use nginx with rtmp module to build live broadcasting application that clients could join it dynamically and I want to do this without reloading nginx.

I want to set `hls_path` in application directive base on input stream name but I have no idea how to do it.
for example in `exec` directive it's possible to reach stream name with `$name` variable but it's not valid in `hls_path` directive.

I test below configuration but nginx created exact `$name` directory instead of stream name.

```
application live {
  live on;
  record off;

  hls  on;
  hls_path /workspace/$name;
  hls_fragment 10s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add hls_nested on; to your config, this creates a sub directory in hls_path using the stream name. Check out the wiki link below.

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#hls_nested

Comment: I wanted more nested directories.
with hls_nested create directory for each variant and master playlist still available in main directory but I want all the variants of a media stream store in directory and each variant store in other directory though hls_nested just make one level subdirectory

Comment: I search for it too much and it seems that rtmp module doesn't have this feature at all.

Comment: You are in a wrong way. one nested level is enough. use your application level logic and stream key for handle file structure and tracking live streams.